# Mongo repository findby with collection - Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-data, findby, mongorepository

I am working on an application made with Groovy and Spring data. Mongo is the database. I have the following class structure:

```
Class A {
  String name;
  List<B> priorities;
}
```

The objects of class A are persisted into mongo. Now, I want to query for all the object which have not null and not blank priorities. I tried with following method:

```
findByPrioritiesNotNull()
```

However, it is not working. It throws an error saying no such method. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findByPrioritiesIsNotNull()` is the correct spelling

Comment: It is fetching the objects, however, the 'priorities' part of all the objects seem to be null. I believe GORM is doing lazy fetching here. Any idea how to configure eager fetching of embedded objects? I got some examples (on google) for mapping objects but not the embedded objects.

Comment: if the collection/object is embedded, it should be fetched by default (you have to try hard to avoid it). check also the mongo collection itself, if the `priorities` field is populated there

Comment: Some of the documents have priorities field as blank and not null (i.e. new ArrayList<>()) I want to skip these records as well. Also, the above mentioned method fetches only 1 record while I have 3 records with not empty list.

Comment: yes, it fetches only 1 record, because it is a `findBy` and not `findAllBy` operation :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no keyword for size.  You would have to provide your own query.  Something like:

```
@Query('{ \\$or: [ {priorities: null}, { priorities: { \\$size: 0 } }] }')
List<A> findByEmptyPriorities()
```